# Ajax request Receives html page as response and the same response is not shown on webpage : Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

My code accepts a registration number, searches in database all the transactions made by that student and return to the page amount paid by student.
Problem is, **Even though I am getting correct response to ajax(checked using chrome dev tool) the same response is not showed on page.And Response is a complete html page**.

Here's my view:

```
<div>
        <input type="text" class="regno" name="reg_no">
        <button class="search_student">Search</button>  
</div>
<table>
    <tr> 
     <?php if(!empty($transactions) and isset($transactions)): 
     foreach ($transactions as $key => $row) { ?>
        <td> <?php echo $row->amount_paid; ?> </td>
     <?php } endif;
      ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the js function:

```
$('.search_student').click(function(){
    //e.preventDefault();

    var regno=$(".regno").val();
    //window.alert(regno);
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "students/get_details",
        data : { 'reg_no' : regno }
    }).done(function(){
            //window.alert("Success");
            //location.reload();
    }).fail(function(){
         window.alert("Could not send data to Server.");
    });
});
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function get_details()
    {
        $roll = $this->input->post('reg_no');              
        $data['transactions'] = $this->student_model->get_student_transactions($roll);
        $data['scripts'] = array ('../bootstrap.min.js','../buttons.js');
        $this->_render_page('allotment', $data);
        //$this->details();
        //var_dump($data['transactions']);
    }
```

The model is working fine, tried and tested.The amount paid appears in ajax response(screenshot attached) but it is not being displayed on webpage.
Thanks in advance!! 
screenshot of the response: http://www.4shared.com/download/twAiI9Odce/upload.jpg?lgfp=3000

Comment: You need to send data only without headers. Preferable way is to json encode it

Comment: But the data is received by controller correctly.Problem is that even though response is showing the amount paid, webpage does not display it.

Answer (score 0):

change controller

```
public function get_details() {
        $roll = $this->input->post('reg_no');
        $data['transactions'] = $this->student_model->get_student_transactions($roll);
        // $data['scripts'] = array ('../bootstrap.min.js','../buttons.js');
        $this->_render_page('allotment', $data);
    }
```

View

```
<table>
    <tr> 
     <?php if(!empty($transactions) and isset($transactions)): 
     foreach ($transactions as $key => $row) { ?>
        <td> <?php echo $row->amount_paid; ?> </td>
     <?php } endif;
      ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

AJAX

```
$('.search_student').click(function () {
        //e.preventDefault();

        var regno = $(".regno").val();
        //window.alert(regno);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "students/get_details",
            data: {'reg_no': regno}
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('table').html(data)
        }).fail(function () {
            window.alert("Could not send data to Server.");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But it didn't yet solve the problem.Still the ajax response in chrome dev window shows the correct output, but the webpage is simply not affected.

Comment: give me the screenshot

Comment: The link of screenshot: http://www.4shared.com/download/twAiI9Odce/upload.jpg?lgfp=3000. (The screenshot shows preview, the html code of preview is coming as response.) Webpage is identical to preview, just without the circled ( correct) output.